# Matplotlib and Jupyter notebook multiple interactive plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am facing the following problem: I need two interactive plots to work at the **same time** on Jupyter, however they are interfering. When I rotate the cell of the first, the second plot stops being interactive and becomes "inline". Other times one of the plots looks like this:

[image: Problem]

The expected result was something like this

[image: Expected]

I imagine the problem is in the implementation I made. As you can see below, I use `plt.something` to put things in the figure (both for plot 1 and plot 2).

[image: Plot 1]

[image: Plot 2]

I'm using the `%matplotlib notebook` environment and tried to implement using `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()`. I would like to know if it is possible to do this type of implementation, where there is no conflict between plots? Maybe I am using matplotlib badly, so I would like some suggestions.

Comment: don't use the pyplot interface. Use the object-oriented interface

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html#the-object-oriented-api

Comment: If matplotlib doesn't seem to work you could try using [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/)

Comment: @PaulH do you have a pratical example (i.e. a notebook)?